# WordPress plugin translation issue

Tags: wordpress

I translated my plugin with poedit, and it works fine on localhost, on new fresh wordpress instalation, but when i uploaded my plugin on server, on exsisting site, some russian charachters missing. I get latin istead, i encoded poedite files with utf8, same in header i have utf8. Where colud be problem, other poedit translation  for romanian works well? In fact russian words are translate, but some letters, still in latin.

Is there some adjustments in config file, or something else? Also i download another wordpress site, and try my plugin on localhost, same results some russian charachters missing. Could be problem with some wordpress settings?

So russian translation works on new fresh basic wordpress instalation, not when i install my plugin on pre - exsiting site.

Comment: Which plugin do you using?

Comment: i created my own plugin

Comment: Ahh. then difficult to identify for us..

Comment: yes i translate it with poedit, wich using gettext lib, maybe some settings in wordpress, create error, i cant figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually string for translations are not stored in the DB, so the MySQL settings are usually not an issue. But to have a correct UTF-8 encoding with translations, make sure these requirements are set:

1. Encode your plugin PHP files in UTF-8 (whithout BOM) and not ANSI
2. Make sure your .po file is encoded in UTF-8, just as the plugin file
3. Check the "header" of your .po file for the correct UTF-8 setting:

> ```
> "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
> "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
> ```

4. Make sure the HTTP-Response is encoded in UTF-8

If all those requirements are set, you should see correct encoded characters.

Comment: All that setting are ok, key question is why my translation works on new fresh instalation of wordpress?

Comment: So it is only not working on this specific server? Have you made sure, that the locale ru_RU or ru_RO is available on this server?

Comment: yes i got that idea, but when i download site and set it on localhost on wamp, still i have issue, so i eliminate that problem

Comment: So if it is nothing with the server setup, it must be an issue of your plugin. But wihtout seeing the code, it's really hard for us to figure out, what is wrong with it.

Comment: Just seeing the code will probably not help. We would need the whole plugin to test it, as issues with encodings are often really hard to find.

Comment: i bet problem is somewhere in wordpress settings, not in my plugin...thats why my plugin have translation when i try it on new fresh wp instalation

Comment: So in a fresh install on the server AND in a fresh install on localhost everything works correctly? And in this problematic installation on the server it doesn't work?

Comment: Thing is i got task for some company, to build plugin contact form, and integrate it on their site, on localhost work, but when i instaled it on site, some char missing, then i tried other comapny site and download it on my pc... same problem occurs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67314/discussion-between-2ndkauboy-and-vladimir-stus).

Answer (score 1):

1. From [How to Fix the Character Encoding Problem in WordPress](https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-fix-the-character-encoding-problem-in-wordpress-1480), try commenting out the following lines:

   ```
   define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
   define('DB_COLLATE','');
   ```
2. Make sure some of those characters are accidentally in latin1. Explained here: [WordPress and MySQL character encoding](http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/wordpress-and-mysql-character-encoding/)
3. I think this post describes the same solution as 1 but still might be helpful. [Seeing Weird Characters On Your Blog? Here’s How To Fix Your WordPress Character Encoding (Latin1 to UTF8)](http://blogsuccessjournal.com/blog-tips-and-advice/wordpress-tips/seeing-weird-characters-on-blog-how-to-fix-wordpress-character-encoding-latin1-to-utf8/)

References on the WordPress Dev StackExchange:

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11247/character-encoding-issue-after-changing-servers
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4236/problems-with-wierd-characters-and-my-plugin

Comment: sorry i tried with this constants many times, not working really wierd situation